# Android check if string changed over time

Tags: android, string, timer

So, my question is fairly simple. I would like to have my program check every minute if a specific string has changed. I was hoping that [TextWatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) would work on strings aswell but unfortunately that wasn't the case. Any similar or even better ways to achieve this?

EDIT: The string which im talking about is from Broadcast receiver.

Comment: You need to be a little more clear on what *eactly* it is you want. If you want to know if the text in an `EditText` has changed then a `TextWatcher` *will* work. Where does this `String` come from?

Answer (score 0):

Save the last received string as a SharedPreferences [see](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html). Compare each received string with the preference to know if it has changed. If it has changed, save the new string.